# Where has now() moved in DateTime 2.12

Tags: python, datetime, zope

I have a product which I'm supporting which uses the now() method from the DateTime module.

```
from DateTime import now
```

However, in DateTime 2.12 this method no longer exists.

Has it been moved to a new location, or is there a new/preferred idiom for getting the current time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime#downloads) page:

**If the function is called with no arguments, then the current date/ time is returned, represented in the timezone of the local machine.**

I browsed through the code of DateTime.py and I didn't see a now() method. So to answer your question, to get the current time just do a `current = DateTime().`

Answer (score 6):

if you are referring to the build in datetime module, since at least python 2.5 `now` is a classmethod of the `datetime` class:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: He seems to use some different module.

Comment: ah, wondered if the case changed between versions, but this is a far better explaination :)

Answer (score 2):

Zope's DateTime module never had a now() method - at least not since I am using Zope which dates back to the late 90s :-)

You are referring to datetime.now() of the Python standard library!?

Comment: Looking at http://svn.zope.org/Zope/branches/2.10/lib/python/DateTime/__init__.py?view=markup there's definitely no such method. And not in any of the older/newer branches either.

Comment: Plone used to monkeypatch it in to DateTime; we cleaned that up in Plone 4. See gladysbixly's answer.